# Php Postgresql, pagination and union

Tags: php, postgresql, pagination

I want to use pagination in php but the problem is there is union in query like:

```
select * from table1 UNION select * from table 2
```

How can i achieve pagination in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you speak of `LIMIT .. OFFSET` then usage is same. eg:

```
t=# select oid,right(datname,3) from pg_database
union all
select oid,right(datname,3) from pg_database
order by oid;
    oid    | right
-----------+-------
         1 | te1
         1 | te1
     13289 | te0
     13289 | te0
     13294 | res
     13294 | res
     17635 | ats
     17635 | ats
   1175099 | t
   1175099 | t
  35836773 | pme
  35836773 | pme
 129444516 | s
 129444516 | s
 185505699 | foo
 185505699 | foo
 281585738 | ump
 281585738 | ump
(18 rows)

Time: 0.404 ms
t=# select oid,right(datname,3) from pg_database
union all
select oid,right(datname,3) from pg_database
order by oid
limit 5 offset 3;
  oid  | right
-------+-------
 13289 | te0
 13294 | res
 13294 | res
 17635 | ats
 17635 | ats
(5 rows)

Time: 0.437 ms
```

Mind that I use `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`, so postgres would not hide duplicated rows

Comment: ok, if i have large no of records coming from union then does it has performance issue ?

Comment: might be. number of rows is one of variables